# Is double summation distributive?

Tags: solution-verification, summation-method

Is double summation distributive like single summation? For example in the proof for linearity of expectations, $E(ax+by)=aE(x)+bE(y)$, it is shown using double summation and they seemed to break it down using distributive properties. Can someone please confirm?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as long as each sum is convergent on its own, for example:
$$\sum_i\sum_j(a_{ij}+b_{ij})=\underbrace{\sum_i\sum_ja_{ij}}_{S_1}+\underbrace{\sum_i\sum_jb_{ij}}_{S_2}$$
as long as both $S_1,S_2$ converge independently

Comment: In particular, true for finite sums (which I surmise is the case seen by the OP).

Comment: Hi, thank you for clearing it up! In the event say, the index i applies to only a (meaning a_i) and j applies to only b (meaning b_j), and i=1 to 3 and j=1 to 4, we would see a coefficient of 4 infront of the summation of a and a coefficient of 3 infront of the summation of b. Did I get that right?

Comment: Yes you are correct